# GDB: reading with the x command doesn't work

Tags: linux, gdb, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to reverse engineer an ELF 64-bit program. 
 I've set a breakpoint on the pointer of a `<strcmp@plt>`. I read [here](https://medium.com/@securosoft/basic-reverse-engineering-using-gdb-ebfb0afca8f4) that the values that are being compared are stored in `rax` and `rbx`. When I use the `x` command (here I use the `x/s` command, to get string output, but i've tried with `x` as well) I get an error saying `<error: Cannont access memory at address *some address*>`, the exact command is `x/s $rax`. The `print` function does work, but that gives me raw data (hex i think?) and I need the string, are there ways to convert the value to string?
 My system is 64-bit windows 10, I'm using gdb in the linux subsystem in windows.

**EDIT**

 I start my GDB session with `gdb R` (name of the program)
Program info: [image: Program info]

 Then I run `disass main` to find the address where my input is compared, that's where the `strcmp@plt` is.
[image: screenshot of the address]

 I copy the address and set a breakpoint using `b * 0x8001168`.

 After I inserted the breakpoint, I run `run TestArg`.

 Now the program halted at my breakpoint.

 I run `info registers` to see if there's something in it, there is.

 When I try `x/s $rax`, I get the following output.
[image: Error with x/s]

 The `print` command does work, but I need the string value.

Comment: Instead of _describing_ what you did, _show_ it (as a complete GDB session). The question "as is" is equivalent to "something didn't work". You need to be more precise if you want someone to help you.

Comment: I've included some screenshots of the outputs and the commands I used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I read here that the values that are being compared are stored in rax and rbx.

That blog post appears to be plain wrong -- there is no way for parameters to `strcmp()` to be in `rax` and `rbx` on `x86_64` -- the [Linux / x86_64 calling convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#List_of_x86_calling_conventions) *requires* them to be in `rdi` and `rsi`.

Looking at their register values, `rax` *happens* to contain the same value as `rdi`, and `rdx` *happens* to contain the same value as `rsi`.

The fact that they

1. use `rax` and `rdx` without mentioning (or apparently understanding) why and,
2. don't actually show the disassembly they refer to

indicates a low-quality content. You should probably stop reading this source, and use something more reliable.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. I can look into $rsi and $rdi. Thank you for the help.